# <!DOCTYPE html> Tag causes strange html behaviour

Tags: css, html

I just started building a cms, and i have not even gotten to the server side scripting yet but i noticed something about my html tag each time i declare the doctype tag in the html the whole html and body tag is always shortened here is a screenshot http://postimg.org/image/h3lj4ozzd/ i've checked my css and html for any mistake but i can't find any error. i was using firefox to run my pages initially, i even switched to chrome, but the error still comes up. i even tried running it on a windows system with wamp (I'm using linux) but the error is still there.i've tried everything i can lay my hands on and they are not working...pls i need suggestions.Thanks

This is the normal document
http://postimg.org/image/xcahm9bsj/

This is the html file with the doctype in it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Welcome to quick score</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id = "top_bar"><p>Home</p></div>

<div id = "two">
<p>Database connection was succesful</p>

</div>

<div id = "one">

<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src = "images/sidebar/dashboard.png" /> Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src = "images/sidebar/attendance.png" /> Attendance sheet </a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src = "images/sidebar/grades.png" /> Grades</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src = "images/sidebar/students.png" /> Students</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

and this is the css file i'm using

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";

}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#top_bar {
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-image: url(images/back3.jpg);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}


#one { background-image: url(images/back3.jpg);
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  color: #ffffff;

}

#one ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 height: 50%;
 padding-top: 20px;

}

#one ul li  {
padding-bottom: 2px;
text-align: left;
display: block;

}

#one ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}


#one ul li a:hover {
        background-color: #ffffff;
}

#one ul li a img {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.position {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#one ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#one ul li:active{
text-decoration: none;
background-color: blue;
padding-left: 48px;
padding-right: 47px;
padding-bottom: 9px;
text-align: center;

}



#two {
  width: 81.5%;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;

}

.login {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #999;

}

form ul li {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;

}

#white {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 40%;
  width: 50%;
}

.buttons {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.register_buttons {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 70px;
}


input[type=submit] {
    border: 1px solid #f44c0e;
    color: #fff;
    background: tomato;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background: #f44c0e;
}
```

Comment: Without a doctype most browsers will render the page in quirks mode. With a doctype, strict mode is used. Also, `<!doctype html>` is the HTML5 doctype, maybe that changes something?

Comment: A question should describe the actual problem encountered, in the question itself. At the general level, we can say that your design is wrong since it is apparently based in Quirks Mode and does not work in “Standards Mode”.

Comment: please tell me how to make it standard...because this is how i've been writing html for the past two years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML5 compliant browsers and a good way to follow the web evolution keep that *doctype* in place.

Have you tried adding:

```
html, body{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Also you should get rid of your `borders`, specially on `body`. Otherwise add:

```
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Comment: i will try your suggestion..but i set the border so i can actually confirm that that the document size is minimizing

Comment: i removed the border and tried what you suggested...but it has no effect...please can you try testing it on your computer.Thanks

Comment: @danidee before: http://jsbin.com/nohoh/1/edit after: http://jsbin.com/nohoh/2/edit

Comment: @danidee but see now the hor. scrollbars? that's cause you set border to `body`. Any way your css seems a bit messy... I would do it completely different... there's other errors in heights adding to the body height, and that's the header height....

Comment: Thanks Roko the new css file you posted solved the problem, the page is displaying normally now.Thanks